# OVH deployment - cakephp 2.x

Tags: cakephp, deployment

It's my first deployment on a server, and I have a white page. I tried several .htaccess, several dispositions, but it never worked.

Here is the /.htaccess file :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$ /app/webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) /app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Here is /www/.htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

My arborescence looks like that :

```
.bash_logout
.bash_profile
.bashrc
.htaccess
.ovhconfig
Config/
Console/
Controller/
Lib/
Locale/
Model/
Plugin/
Test/
Vendor/
View/
app/
cakephp/
index.html
tmp/
www/
```

And in www, the content of app/webroot. I changed debug to 0, I tried several things, but I don't understand much of that. Does anyone know what's wrong or missing?

Comment: What is the path of Document root of your website?

Comment: It must be app/webroot, so I would like to know if I'm doing things right

Comment: Can anyone tell me what precisely has to be in the www ?

Comment: You're supposed to put all the files to a Cake site into the folder you're hosting.  If that's your www, then put all your files in there.  You shouldn't be rearranging Cake's normal file structure at all.

Comment: @Charline You are not sure about website root folder? tell me your root folder name and then I can answer your question...

Comment: it's www. I changed index.php to have the configurations I need : path to cake, name of app folder, path of the parent folder of app, but it must be wrong, because I still have a white page. Does cake folder have to be named Cake with a C or c ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out : my index.php files weren't correct. I used the real root of the server, homz.800/, instead of just /, and it worked. To have css working properly, I've put the content of webroot, in the app folder, in www.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good practice to keep your `app/` & `lib/` folders outside the public box.

Main directory structure (`/` is your root directory) :

```
/
  .bash_history
  .bash_logout
  .bash_profile
  .bashrc
  .forward
  .htaccess
  cake_2.x.x/
    app/
      Config/
      Console/
      [...]
    lib/
      Cake/
        [lib_subfolders]
        [...]
  www/
    .htaccess
    index.php
    [js]
    [css]
    [images]
    [...]
```

**Here is the first `.htaccess` in root path `/`**

```
SetEnv PHP_VER 5_3
SetEnv REGISTER_GLOBALS 0
```

**The `.htaccess` in `www/`**

```
SetEnv PHP_VER 5_3
SetEnv REGISTER_GLOBALS 0

Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^your_domain.com$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.your_domain.com/$1  [QSA,L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

**Here is the index.php file inside `www/` (important)**

```
[...]
if (!defined('ROOT')) {
    define('ROOT', DS . 'homez.800' . DS . 'your_domain');
}
[...]
if (!defined('APP_DIR')) {
    define('APP_DIR', 'cake_2.x.x' . DS . 'app');
}
[...]
define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', ROOT . DS . 'cake_2.x.x' . DS . 'lib');
```

**Take care that your `debug` mode was set to `0` in `app/Config/core.php`**

```
Configure::write('debug', 0);
```

**No need of `.htaccess` and `index.php` inside `app/` you can remove them.**

Hope it will help!

Comment: Thank you for that answer, but my upper answer was to say I had found out. As I had to wait some hours, I forgot to validate it and I didn't come back since then. Sorry for that

Comment: No worries, I just posted my configuration in case it could help someone. Thanks.